Turing's Argument For Unsolvable Problems
At the heart of Turing's article for the Science News about solvable and unsolvable problems there is argument that he uses to show that there is no systematic way to decide whether a particular type of puzzle, a substitution puzzle is solvable.  But in the middle of the argument he makes a remark that is not clear for me.
An outline of the argument is:
Let $P(R,S)$ stand for "the puzzle whose rules are described by the row of symbols $R$ and whose starting position is described by $S$".
(i) Owing to the special form that is used to describe the rules i.e. reducing them to a string of symbols, then we can consider $P(R,R)$ where the ‘rules’ also serve as starting position.
(ii)  A puzzle is said to have ‘come out’ if one reaches either the position B or the position W, and the rules do not permit any further moves.
(iii) The rules $R$ of the puzzles can be classified:
Class I is to consist of rules $R$ such that $P(R,R)$ 'comes out' with the end result $W$.
Class II is to include all other cases, i.e. either $P(R,R)$ does not come out, or comes out with the end result $B$, or else $R$ does not represent a puzzle with unambiguous moves.
(iv) Assume that there that there is a systematic procedure, $K$ that can represent the classification described in (iii), with the following properties:
$K$ has unambiguous moves.
$P(K,R)$ always comes out whatever $R$.
If $R$ is in Class I, then $P(K,R)$ has end result $B$.
If $R$ is in Class II, then $P(K,R)$ has end result $W$.
It is important to note that there is no reason for selecting $B$ or $W$ for the result of $K$.
(vi)  The question is - which Class does $K$ belongs to?
The properties of $K$ tell us that we must get end result $B$ if $K$ is in Class I and $W$ if it is in Class II, whereas the definitions of the classes (iii) tell us that the end results must be the other way round.  Therefore the assumption (iv) that there was a systematic procedure for telling whether puzzles come out produces a contradiction and therefore doesn't exist.
The problem for me is that at step (iv).  Turing says - see page 592 in the attached paper - "The opposite choice would be equally possible, and would hold for a slightly different set of rules $K^\prime$, which however we do not choose to favour with our attention." Where I am struggling is that if the properties of  $K^\prime$ were $W$ in Class I and $B$ in Class II then there is no contradiction - how is the remark of any help?
I have come up with the following thoughts:
(a) by stage (iv) a contradiction has been shown and therefore no more needs to be said, therefore his remarks about $K^\prime$ was thinking out loud.
(b) If the classification (iii) was reversed then we would get a contradiction but I feel that this is not what Turing is saying.
(c) I tried different ideas about the rules for $K^\prime$ e.g. add rules to $K^\prime$ could include:
If the end result is $W$ then switch the end result to $B$, and
If the end result is $B$ then switch the end result to $W$.
But this looks very clumsy and isn't what he meant either because the results 'come out' the same as the original argument and I'm sure that this is not what he meant.
I'm clearly missing something - what is it?

Obviously I cannot be sure what Turing was thinking while writing the basis for the paper you're citing. It is true that $K'$ doesn't matter for the specific reasoning in the paper, because it isn't contradictory.
But, if you do consider $K'$, what it is is a hypothetical puzzle that accurately reports the class of every other puzzle, using $B$ to mean Class II since that is the class that contains the puzzle that come out $B$. While this is not directly contradictory, it is possible to modify $K'$ to obtain a puzzle that satisfies all the premises for $K$, by swapping the results as you mentioned. So, it turns out that $K'$ cannot exist either.
In fact, a typical proof for the undecidability of the halting problem on Turing machines actually builds something like $K'$ as an intermediate step. You start with a puzzle $H$ such that $P(H,R*S)$ supposedly reports if/how $P(R,S)$ comes out, similarly to the two classes (where $R*S$ pairs up a puzzle description with a starting position in a way that $H$ can handle). Then you modify it to build $K'$ such that $P(K', R) = P(H, R*R)$. Then you invert the result to get the puzzle $K$.
So, often $K'$ is involved in the actual proof. In this article Turing is only describing the final list of contradictory properties for the rules $K$, and you are just expected to accept that $K$'s existence is a consequence of the existence of something like $H$ (or even vaguer criteria). But full proofs show how to build $K$ from $H$ in detail, and $K'$ will often appear.

I followed up on the point about the proof of the The Halting Problem and how it builds something like $K^\prime$ and $H$. There are thousands of descriptions of The Halting Problem on the web but the best one that I found is in Marvin Minsky's book "Computation: Finite and Infinite Machines" pp146 - 149 ( https://archive.org/details/computationfinit0000mins/page/n5/mode/2up ) which I feel best describes the point that you made.  Following the the form of his argument: because $K$ produces a contradiction, therefore it doesn't exists and neither does "$K^\prime$ , and subsequently $H$.
